# two-digit string addition with no number at the end

Tags: c, string, addition

I have to add two digit strings, meaning 1234 12+34 (at least that's what i gather). I wrote a program that does this expect for one exception, that is when the last number doesn't have a pair it wont add properly.

Here is the code i have:

```
void main()

{


char string[1000];
int count,sum=0,x,y;

printf("Enter the string containing both digits and alphabet\n");
scanf("%s",string);

for(count=0;count < string[count]; count++)
{
        x=(string[count] - '0') * 10;
        y=(string[count+1] - '0') + x;
        sum += y;
        count++;      
}

printf("Sum of string in two digit array is =%d\n",sum);

}
```

so basically if i have 123 the program does 12+(30-48), instead of 12+3. Ive been sitting on it for a while, and cant figure out how to fix that issue, any tips or advice would be welcomed.

(Strings like 1234 or 4567 will do 12+34 and 45+67)

Comment: `count < string[count]` ??

Comment: What would it do for input of `12`? or `1234567`?

Comment: count < string[count], ya looking at it now its kind of odd, but it worked.
if you put 12 it will sum as 12, if you put 1234567 it will do 12+34+56+(70-48) which is the problem, if it was 12+34+56+78 it would be fine

Comment: `containing both digits and alphabet` ??

Comment: It would also add alphabet, but i just need it to add digits

Comment: That is all very well explaining what you want to add but you omitted to say what the result of your examples (eg 45+67) should be, or the result of alpha addition. What is "abcd", "ab"+"cd", equal to?

Comment: sorry my mistake. So 4567 would be 45+67=112, and abcd would be ab+cd=1102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char string[1000];
    char digits[3] = {0};
    int i, j, x, sum = 0;

    printf("Enter the string containing both digits and alphabet\n");
    scanf("%999s", string);
    for(j = i = 0; string[i]; ++i){
        if(isdigit(string[i])){
            digits[j++] = string[i];
            if(j==2){
                sscanf(digits, "%d", &x);
                sum += x;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(j==1){
        digits[j] = 0;
        sscanf(digits, "%d", &x);
        sum += x;
    }
    printf("Sum of string in two digit array is = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. You didnt have to go through the trouble of writing the whole thing, but ya this does exactly what i needed it to do.